# bootstrap tagsinput remove items using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using bootstrap tagsinput field. In that I am using below jquery to add items that code works successfully.

```
$('#tag').tagsinput('add', { "value": 1 , "text": "Amsterdam"   , "continent": "Europe"    });
```

Now i need to remove the added item using jquery. I tried that below code

```
 $('#tag').tagsinput('remove', { "value": 1 , "text": "Amsterdam"   , "continent": "Europe"    });
```

But it seems to be not working .How can i remove items using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have done this mistake you have used:

```
 $('#tag').tagsinput('remove', { "value": 1 , "text": "Amsterdam"   , 
 "continent": "Europe"    });
```

but i think that it should be :

```
 $('#tag').tagsinput('remove', { value: 1 , text: 'Amsterdam'   , 
continent: 'Europe'    });
```

Try doing this I hope that works.

Comment: I think you also have to mention a specific id of the tags to remove them.

Comment: i tried that.Not working . This is my actual code `$(".typeahead_lang").on('itemRemoved', function(event) {
$('#typeahead_lang_en').tagsinput('remove', { value: event.item['value'] , text: event.item['text']    });
$('#typeahead_lang_ja').tagsinput('remove', { value: event.item['value'] , text: event.item['text']    });
})`
But now it returns thi serror `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: try consoling things inside the function it can be a chance that there can be any other error